# DOMPDF Images lose quality when converting to PDF

Tags: image, dompdf, blurry

When using DOMPDF the barcodes and QR codes on my HTML document (generated with Zend Barcode library) display blurry, not sharp like they do on the HTML where they only have just black and white pixels. I've read all I could find on google. Changing the value of DOMPDF_DPI just affects the size of the images but they show blurry in any case. I have the same problem with div borders. A simple 1px black border of a div shows blurry. In this case is just an aesthetic problem but with the bar codes the barcode reader struggles to scan them so I need to solve it.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: What format are the images output in? PNG images go through quite a bit of processing, which could be responsible for the blurriness.

Comment: @BrianS I'm experiencing the same problem. Just did a test of the same image in both `.jpg` and `.png` with the same result. :\

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I don't really have a suggestion for fixing the problem just yet. You could try inserting the image using the cpdf library instead. The main drawback to that method is you have to position it manually.